# css floats and its stack order

Tags: css, css-position

I am reviewing the floats property which i learned before,I found a simple issue about floated elements with its own stacking order, the code as:

Example 1:

```css
.box-1{
  background: teal;
  width:100px; height:100px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<p> this is the text for the testing purpose<p>
```

I totally understand the text will wrap around the the box which is right next to the box-1, but when there is no text elements only two div boxes:

Example 2:

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.box-1{
  background:teal; 
  float:left;
}
.box-2{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
```

This time the `.box-1` will overlap the `.box-2` since it was floated and taken from the normal document flow.

So my questions are:

1. Since the `p` tag is a block element and it could be considered as a box. but why in the example 2 the `p` tag is moving to the right after the `box-1`? but in the example 1 there is totally different behavior?
2. It is because of the floated elements has same stack order like `p` tags and both of them have higher stacking order than the non-floated box as `.box-2` here?

Comment: what you're trying to do exactly. explain with short note. Its too difficult understand your problem. you want to fill the blue background for `box-2`?

Comment: Hi there, the code example is for the test purpose, i listed my questions at the bottom which i am wondering why the box-2 is not moving to the right beside the box-1 but the p tag can do that? since the p tag is a block element too.

Comment: this is a very interesting case. This is definitely caused by the `width` `height` setting. Not sure why, but you can resolve this by setting `box-2` to be `display: inline-block`. If you remove the background from `box-1` you'll notice that `box-2`'s  background i actually sitting behind it.

Answer (score 4):

I am going to add more explanation as I think the accepted answer omitted some important parts and didn't provide a real explanation. Let's start with the definition of float from the [MDN documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed
>   along the left or right side of its container, **allowing text and**
>   **inline elements to wrap around it**. The element is removed from the
>   **normal flow** of the web page, though **still remaining a part of the flow**
>   (in contrast to absolute positioning).

So yes float behave like absolute positioning but not exactly because element is still a part of the flow.

Now both of your examples behave exactly the same, the only difference is that in the first one you have text. So the float element doesn't push the `p` like you think **but overlap it** and push only the text. If you inspect the element you will see this:

[image]

So `p` is a block element and behave exactly like the `box-2` in your second example and the floated element `box-1` is above it. This confirms that in both examples we have the same thing but in the first one we have text inside the block element `p` and **unlike** absolute positioned element, floated element pushs text as described above.

**Now why the floated element is above the `p` tag and above the `box-2`?**

You can find this answer within [the specificaton of the painting order](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html). Both elements are not positioned and one is floated:

> 4. For **all its in-flow, non-positioned, block-level descendants** in tree
>      order: If the element is a block, list-item, or other block
>      equivalent:
> 5. All non-positioned **floating descendants**, in tree order.

As we can see, we first draw the **in-flow element** in the step (4) (in your case the `p` tag and the `box-2`) then we print the **floating ones** in the step (5) (the `box-1`).

---

To avoid such things you have two solutions (like provided in other answers):

1. You clear float which is a common solution used in order to avoid element being affected by the floating behavior.
2. You make the `box-2` an inline-block element because **inline-block behave like inline-elements** and they are also pushed by floated element

Answer (score 1):

I believe I understand the issue now (somewhat). Because they have the same dimensions, and because `float: left` kind of acts like `display: absolute` while maintaining text space, it's pushed `box-2`'s text to the bottom.

You can get around this setting `display: inline-block` for `box-2` and interestingly enough, putting an `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` also fixes it.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

.box-1{
  float:left;
}
.box-2{
  background:blue;
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1">box-1</div>
<div class="box box-2">box-2</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, i shouldn't adding text "box-1" and "box-2" into the two div tags for leading misunderstanding.

Comment: I just wondering when floated box-1 to left, why the p tag text can be right beside it and why the box-2 is overlapped. But from your suggestion: adding  "display:inline-block" on box-2 is work

Comment: @JianNCI It's because of the forced `width` `height` if you remove that from box-2, it will show it like the normal `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just add the `overflow:hidden` in your css for `.box` class.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box-1{
  background:teal; 
  float:left;
}
.box-2{
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1">box-1</div>
<div class="box box-2">box-2</div>
```